# convert excel file row to column in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsql-package

I have excel file with this format as shown in the Image.
and I want to import it in my Oracle Database in column format , I'm using APEX Platform as well.

All the data is in row format and this is just a sample , because this file has maybe 20 rows
but huge number of columns.

Input :

[image: Row Format Data]

My question is , What is the best way to upload data with this format to Oracle DB
but to be with this format.

I tried pivot/unpivot but was not good because I have huge records of data.

This is the output I need.

[image: column data]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could enhance the **XLSX_PARSER** to handle a large number of columns. You didn't say how many, but I enhanced the package to handle 175 columns.

Check out my answer here, to a more-generic question of loading Excel into Apex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67022896/1529154