# Oracle Apex load excel data .xlsm without plugin

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to load data from excel to table . i.e. upload excel from apex application and then load the oracle database table. I have been advised to avoid plugin so am looking for oracle apex processed using which i can do this.

Any advice/steps/links to information would be very helpful.

Th file to be loaded is .xlsm with macros but the macros can be ignored.

Apex 20.2

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built-in for allowing your users to load an Excel file into your Apex app and store the data into a database table.

Personally, I've used Carsten Czarski's **XLSX_PARSER** package with good results. The source code is clean and I even enhanced it to parse for my custom needs.

- https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/easy-xlsx-parser%3a-just-with-sql-and-plsql

I found these two good references via Google:

- Jeff Kemp's great review of many possible solutions for various data formats, including Excel - https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2018/11/load-spreadsheet-data-into-apex/
- Anton Scheffer's Excel2Collections package - https://github.com/antonscheffer/excel2collections

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it without even using the Data loading wizard provided by oracle apex, so here is the video, in which I have in detail explained how you can do it, with simple 2 steps.

Oracle APEX Upload Excel Data into Table or Collection in an Easy way without a Data loading feature
Link: https://youtu.be/ihJGYV0yDWE

Comment: Please list the steps here and use external links as secondary examples.