# Is there a way to insert data from multiple sheets excel file all together in a process using oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have question
Is there a way to insert data from multiple sheets excel file all together  in one process using oracle apex application to the database?

I did a process that insert only 1 sheet per file
Is there a way to insert all sheets together?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great response here on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67022896/527513

Carsten has another good article on using the apex_data_parser package
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex-data-parser-package